# Copyright character in sed

Tags: utf-8, sed, character

I'm trying to remove all lines containing the copyright character (among other things, in a bash script), but it's not working at all:

```
cat $srcdir/$txtfile |
sed "s/.*©.*/d" |
cat > $tgtdir/$txtfile
```

does nothing. However, running

```
echo blah © blah | sed "s/.*©.*//g"
```

in the terminal correctly yields

```
blah  blah
```

I'm using SciTE set to UTF-8 encoding, so the first block of code above is exactly what I see in the editor. Any ideas on how I could represent it in an editor so sed will recognise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the octal representation of © which is `251`

```
$ echo blah © blah | sed 's/\o251/X/'
blah  blah
```

That is on "oh" and not a zero.

To delete lines containing that character, use

```
sed '/\o251/d'
```

Comment: I changed the 0 in the last line to o (typo, I guess), and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sed command doesn’t look right. Try

```
sed '/©/d'
```

And check that the appropriate locale environment variable set in the shell in which the script runs. For example, I use

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `grep` instead

```
grep -v '©'
```